# Cannot create git repo in davfs2 mount

Tags: linux, git, debian, webdav, mount

On Linux Debian 9, I'm trying to create a git (ver. 1:2.11.0-3+deb9u2) repository within a Cryptomator (ver. 1.3.2) WebDAV server mounted via davfs2 (ver. 1.5.4-2+b1). After running `git init` to create the git repo, I get the following error:

```
error: could not lock config file /home/nonrootuser/Documents/mounteddrive/gitrepo/.git/config: Permission denied
fatal: could not set 'core.repositoryformatversion' to '0'
```

Same issue persists with nonrootuser and root.

To reproduce:

git and davfs2 are available via Debian repositories. Cryptomator 1.3.2 is available here:
https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator/releases/tag/1.3.2

Create a blank folder for the davfs2 mount:
`cd /home/nonrootuser/Documents/`
`mkdir mounteddrive`

Create a vault with Cryptomator and unlock it. For the unlocked vault, click the dropdown arrow and select **Copy WebDAV URL**. Paste the WebDAV URL into the following command and run in terminal:

`mount -t davfs -o gid=nonrootuser,uid=nonrootuser pasteWebDAVURLhere /home/nonrootuser/Documents/mounteddrive`
(hit enter twice, leaving Username and Password blank)

The Cryptomator vault is now mounted to the folder mounteddrive.

In terminal, run the following:
`cd /home/nonrootuser/Documents/mounteddrive`
`mkdir gitrepo`
`cd gitrepo`
`git init`

Here you should see the error described above. However, a .git folder is still created within the gitrepo directory. When running `ls -la` in gitrepo, it seems to indicate I have the appropriate permissions, and I can create arbitrary files within the .git folder; what I cannot create is an empty file called config.lock, which I believe is what git is trying to do.

This may be completely off-base, but I've tried turning locks on and off (see `use_locks`) in the davfs2.conf file that can be edited by running the following as root:
`mousepad /etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf`

To try to obtain the appropriate permissions to create config.lock, I've tried changing my git user.name to "root" and "nonrootuser":
`git config --system user.name "root"`
`git config --global user.name "root"`

and
`git config --system user.name "nonrootuser"`
`git config --global user.name "nonrootuser"`

I've also tried running the following in the gitrepo folder as both root and nonrootuser:
`chmod -R 777 .git`

However, `git init` still returns an error.

git is working fine on my system outside of cryptomator/davfs2 mounts. I've not used davfs2 previously without cryptomator, so I don't know if the former, latter, or both are the problem.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: It might be worth indicating that you are actually logged in as "nonrootuser" and with details about the permissions for /home/nonrootuser/Documents/mounteddrive

Comment: Yes, I'm logged in as "nonrootuser". Permissions for mounteddrive:  `drwxr-xr-x 49 nonrootuser nonrootuser       1664 Jan 31 21:08 mounteddrive`